# Touch Not Working Even without Any Errors and The Right Function

Tags: lua, touch, coronasdk

Below is my code for a game and its written in LUA with Corona SDK.

The touch function is not working in the simulator.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
    local physics = require "physics"
    physics.start()       
    --jet    
    local jet = display.newImage("redJet.png")
    jet.x = 100
    jet.y = 100
    physics.addBody(jet,"dynamic", {density=.1, bounce=0.1, friction=.2,radius=12})

    function acivateJets(self,event)
        self.applyForce(0, -1.5, self.x, self.y)
    end 


    function touchScreen(event)
      if event.phase == "began" then
      jet.enterFrame = activateJets
      Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", jet)
      end

      if event.phase == "ended" then
      end

    end

    Runtime:addEventListener("touch", touchScreen)
```

Comment: (1) The `if event.phase == "ended" then end` don't do anything so you can remove it. (2) You are setting `jet` as `local` (`local jet`), which makes me wonder if the scope allows you to access it from inside a function `touchScreen` as you are doing here `jet.enterFrame = activateJets` or not.

Comment: @acarlstein regarding your wonder if the `local jet` is accessible from `touchScreen`, it is. It's an upvalue for the `touchScreen` function and a reference to it is kept alive because of that fact.

Comment: The names don't match. The name of the function `function acivateJets(self,event)` doesn't match the name used here `jet.enterFrame = activateJets`. One says `acivateJets`, the other say `activateJets` (Assuming the code was copied and pasted).

Comment: @acarlstein nice catch!